# ffmpeg rtmp streaming process exit

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm using ffmpeg to capture jpeg images from an rtmp stream. Here is the command I use:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -threads 4 -i rtmp://..../chat/mp4:<variable>.mp4 
-q:v 0.6 -r 15 -s 320x240 /frames/10021237_data/frame-%0999d.jpg

ffmpeg version N-55388-g9386f33 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  8 2013 14:07:38 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 41.100 / 52. 41.100
  libavcodec     55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavformat    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://......./mp4:10021237.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1.92 tbr, 1k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: nellymoser, 44100 Hz, mono, flt
[swscaler @ 0x1910000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/frames/10021237_data/frame-%0999d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.13.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

However after a few minutes I get this line (before the process exits):

```
video:5264kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000408%
```

What exactly is the "muxing overhead" and why is it causing a crash? Can I solve this or get it some other way (by restarting the process when it exits) ?

EDIT:

Actually it's not a crash. I'm running this command from a PHP CLI when a stream starts:

```
 $command = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$rtmp." -q:v 0.6 -r 12 -s 320x240 ".__DIR__."/".$dir."/".$naming." >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &";
shell_exec($command);
```

but when one stops streaming all the ffmpeg processes end. Is there a way to make them independent?

Even opening 2 terminals and running the command (with different rtmp s)in each (for different streams), killing one of them closes the other one also.

Bottom line is: How can I make 2 ffmpeg instances independent so as killing one does not kill the other. Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: Two commands are generally independent of each other.  If input stops arriving, it may time out and exit. Can you explain how are you killing one of them?